# What minimum maintenance should I do to get my cycle to a shop where it can be looked over professionally?

Tags: honda, motorcycle

It's been in the garage all winter. It starts, but I'm nervous about getting it to a mechanic (about 10 miles away). It's a 2007 Honda Rebel 250cc.

I have zero maintenance experience. None. A couple years ago the engine on my cycle seized because I didn't notice an oil leak. But I'm in a new place and I don't know any mechanics yet; I really don't want to F up another engine.

The oil is low, and needs to be changed. I fixed the tire pressure. That's all I know to check! I'm sure there are other things I should look at before taking it out; what is important? I'd rather not have it die en route to a mechanic... *I* would rather not die en route too!

Comment: Rep too low to tag with honda-rebel.

Comment: How does this question rate vs the meta post http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/making-a-site-for-professionals ? It's obviously my first post here, and I suspect it's too basic for the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have concerns that the motorcycle is not safe to ride then don't ride it.It is impossible to say it is safe to ride without knowing a lot of details.My suggestion would be to contact the shop that will be doing the work.Many dealers have a pickup service.In some cases it is free if they do a certain amount of repairs.In other words if you spend enough the will take remove the pickup charge.While at the repair shop ask them to give you some pointers on a preride check list you can perform yourself.

Comment: Great answer. +1. Motorcycles aren't cars. Trying to limp a questionable motorcycle to a shop could result in a lot more physical personal injury than trying to limp a car to a shop.

Answer (score 1):

I'd top off the oil and check all the standard stuff (tire pressure, lights, brakes) and then drive it over.  Maybe take a look at the battery and top off any cells that look low (unless it's a maintenance-free type, of course).  Did you fill the fuel tank and put some fuel stabilizer in it before you parked it for the winter?  If not, then you could have some rust inside the tank that will flake off and possibly clog your fuel filter, be sure to have the shop check that.  If you didn't use a fuel stabilizer I'd recommend draining the tank and putting in some fresh fuel (you can put the drained fuel in your car, a gallon or so of old fuel mixed with several gallons of fresh stuff won't hurt anything).

Answer (score 1):

While you are at the dealership, invest in an Owner's Manual.  It will outline all the things needed to be done to store it for winter or inclement weather times as well as removing it from storage.  The other thing to invest in is a battery tender.  It will prolong the life of your battery and save you money in the long run.

The only other thing that has not been mentioned so far was checking the tires for cracking.  IF they are, they will need to be replaced.  You only have 2, and they are your only contact with the road.